# How can I set the initial state of the Bootstrap toggle to be collapsed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, toggle

I am creating a toggle where when a line of text is clicked, more text drops down below and when clicked again, the text collapses.  I am trying to get the text color to be blue when collapsed and red when open.  I have this working except on the initial page load the text color does not appear as the collapsed color.  Thank you for any help.

```css
.accordion-toggle {
    color: rgb(176, 26, 33) !important;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
    color: #3a70a1 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" id="question1">

                Line of text.
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body answer">
                More text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using 3.x markup for Bootstrap 4. There is no longer `panel` or `in`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the class `.collapsed` is only being added once it the accordion really has been collapsed at least once, and therefore not upon loading the page.

To solve this, you could add a third state for the text, `.initial`, which also has a blue color. You then need to remove this state manually with javascript as soon as the accordion has been opened, and has therefore left its initial state.

Here is a demonstration:

```js
function removeInitial(el) {
  el.classList.remove("initial");
}
```

```css
.accordion-toggle {
  color: rgb(176, 26, 33) !important;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
  color: #3a70a1 !important;
}

.initial {
  color: #3a70a1 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle initial" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" id="question1" onclick="removeInitial(this)">

                Line of text.
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body answer">
          More text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```